# Poor sound quality until I click on settings

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-11, dell-latitude

I have a windows 11 Latitude 5520 paired with a Jabra Evolve 20 ms headset.

When I play music I heard it in a "telephonic quality.
If I go in windows 11 settings under: System > Sound > (Headset Earphone) Properties.
In the exact moment I open the Properties tab the audio quality raises to a normal pleasant quality.

When the music stops and I resume it I have to repeat the process to make the sound quality be normal again, by going in the previous tab Sound and click again in my headset (Headset Earphone) Properties.

I enabled/disabled Spatial audio and Audio enhancements but it happens regardless.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Sounds like the Bluetooth hands-free profile switching over to A2DP when you go into settings. Bluetooth headsets are almost universally awful when the microphone is involved. You might be able to disable the microphone and hands-free side to permanently in the sound settings for the devices: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsNfc.png

Comment: @Mokubai That was my immediate tough as well but Jabra Evolve 20 ms is wired.